# Java Payroll keep showing 0.00 for net pay

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Output run:

```
 Payroll Computation

 Enter number of hours worked (00.0) <0 for Quick exit>: 39

 Enter first number of hours straight (integer or 0 to disable):40

 Enter hourly rate of worker (00.00): 10

 Gross pay is : $390.00
 Tax is       : 7%
 Net pay is   : $0.00
```

Net pay is supposed to be 362.70

So the actual output should be something like the below:

```
Gross pay is : $390.00
Tax is        : 7%
Net pay is   : $362.70
```

What details do I miss here?
Is it something that I have done wrong in the code or is it anything else?
Need your help/assistance to get value of Net pay

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.text.NumberFormat; 
import java.math.*; 
import java.util.Locale; 
class Assign2 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
          CalPayroll cpr=new CalPayroll(); 
          cpr.acceptPay(); 

    } 
}
```

**CallPayroll** class

```
class CalPayroll extends Pay 
{ 
    Screen sc=new Screen(); 
    Scanner stdin=new Scanner(System.in); 
    NumberFormat dollars=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); 
    Pay p=new Payroll(); 
    public void displayinfo() 
    { 
          double _gross=super.calc_payroll(); 
          super.tax(_gross); 
          double _net= p.calc_payroll(); 
          System.out.println("Gross pay is : "+dollars.format(_gross)); 
          System.out.println("Tax is       : "+taxrate+"%"); 
          System.out.println("Net pay is   : "+dollars.format(_net)); 

    } 
    public void acceptPay() 
    { 
          Accept ac = new Accept(); 
          CalPayroll cp=new CalPayroll(); 
          float h,r; 
          int hs; 
          char s; 
          do 
          {     
                System.out.println("Payroll Computation"); 
                System.out.println(" "); 
                System.out.println("Enter number of hours worked (00.0) <0 for Quick exit>: "); 
                h=stdin.nextFloat(); 
                cp.setHours(h); 
                if(h>0) 
                { 
                      System.out.println("Enter first number of hours straight (integer or 0 to disable):"); 
                      hs=stdin.nextInt(); 
                      System.out.println("Enter hourly rate of worker (00.00): "); 
                      r=stdin.nextFloat(); 
                      sc.scrollscreen('=',65,2); 
                      cp.setHrsStr(hs); 
                      cp.setRate(r); 

                      sc.scrollscreen(1); 
                      cp.displayinfo(); 
                      sc.scrollscreen(1); 

                      System.out.println("e to exit, any other letter + <Enter> to continue"); 
                      s=stdin.next().charAt(0); 

                } 
                else 
                { 
                      System.out.println("e to exit, any other letter + <Enter> to continue"); 
                      s=stdin.next().charAt(0); 
                } 

          }while(s!='e'&&s!='E'); 

    } 
}
```

**Pay** class

```
class Pay 
{ 
    private float Hours, Rate; 
    private int HrsStr; 
    public int taxrate=0; 

    public void setHours(float a) 
    { 
          Hours=a; 
    } 
    public void setRate(float a) 
    { 
          Rate=a; 
    } 
    public void setHrsStr(int a) 
    { 
          if(a<0) 
          { 
                HrsStr=0; 
          } 
          else 
          { 
                HrsStr=a; 
          } 
    } 
    public float getHours() 
    { 
          return Hours; 
    } 
    public float getRate() 
    { 
          return Rate; 
    } 
    public int getHrsStr() 
    { 
          return HrsStr; 
    } 


    public double calc_payroll() 
    { 
          double gross; 
          gross=getHours()*getRate(); 
          return gross; 
    } 

    public void tax(double a) 
    { 
          if(a>=0&&a<=399.99) 
             taxrate=7; 
          else if(a>=400.00&&a<=899.99) 
             taxrate=11; 
          else 
             taxrate=17; 
    } 

} 
class Payroll extends Pay 
{ 
    double net; 
    double _gross; 

    public double calc_payroll() 
    { 
          _gross=super.calc_payroll(); 
          super.tax(_gross); 
          net=_gross-(_gross*taxrate/100); 
          return net; 
    } 
} 
class Screen 
{ 
    public static void scrollscreen(int a) 
     { 
           for(int i=0;i<a;i++) 
           { 
                System.out.println(" "); 
           }   
     } 
     public static void scrollscreen(char c, int a, int b) 
     { 
           for(int i=0;i<b;i++) 
           { 
                for(int j=0;j<a;j++) 
                { 
                      System.out.print(c); 
                } 
                System.out.println(" "); 
           } 
   } 
} 


class Accept 
{ 
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); 
    public int acceptInputInt()   
     { 
           return in.nextInt(); 
       } 

    public char acceptInputChar() 
     { 
          return in.next().charAt(0); 
   } 
    public float AcceptInputFloat() 
     { 
          return in.nextFloat();   
     } 
   public double AcceptInputDouble() 
   { 
          return in.nextDouble(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Can't tell. The relevant code in `Pay` and `Payroll` wasn't provided.

Comment: And what is `CalParoll` and `Accept` ? LOL

Comment: My bad i forgot to copy and paste Pay and Payroll

Comment: now its provided! CalParoll is a subclass of Pay which invoke cal_payroll of superclass and tax() method in order to calculate Net Pay

Comment: Minor note: Start using: `public static void main(String... args)` instead of `String[]` args` or `String args[]`.

Comment: You make good use of classes. Make sure you use camelCase for method names (no underscores) and method names should not start with upper case letters. Also, add an empty line between methods for readability.

Comment: Use clear readable variable names: No single double character variable names..yuck :0

Comment: Variables should start with lowercase too.Only class names are upper cased :) - It's a code review! lol

Comment: thanks for the review but those names are not up to me. It is an assignment from school. I just copied the names from the instructions so I can't change anything of names. :( I will add an empty line between methods for sure Anyways, do you have any idea to fix that code to show value of Net pay? Is there any error to fix it? because I only get gross pay and tax rate when I run it but i need to get Net pay

Comment: Tell your instructor he needs to review the Java recommended Code Conventions and teach the proper standards. Here is a link you can give him: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

It fails simply because you calculate `p.calc_payroll()` from within the `cp` payroll object! The `p` object doesn't have any hours or rates set, so it returns 0.

You expect the following to return your expected output:

> ```
> public void acceptPay() 
> { 
>   ...
>   cp.setHrsStr(hs); 
>   cp.setRate(r); 
>
>   sc.scrollscreen(1); 
>   cp.displayinfo(); 
>   ...
> }
> ```

Which further calls:

> ```
> class CalPayroll extends Pay 
> { 
>     ...
>     Pay p=new Payroll(); 
>     public void displayinfo() 
>     { 
>           double _gross=super.calc_payroll(); 
>           super.tax(_gross); 
>           double _net= p.calc_payroll(); 
>           System.out.println("Gross pay is : "+dollars.format(_gross)); 
>           System.out.println("Tax is       : "+taxrate+"%"); 
>           System.out.println("Net pay is   : "+dollars.format(_net)); 
>
>     }
> ```

Here you see that `p = new PayRoll()`, but no further action is set to actually set the hours and rates for `p`. This leads to the internal setting of `_net = p.calc_payroll()` resulting in setting `_net = 0`.

How it is supposed to work I'm not sure, but this is most probably the reason why it only prints 0. I don't have a Java compiler available, but I think the following would fix your issue:

```
class CalPayroll extends Pay 
{ 
    ...
    // Pay p=new Payroll(); // Not needed...
    public void displayinfo() 
    { 
          double _gross=super.calc_payroll(); 
          super.tax(_gross); 
          double _net= calc_payroll(); // Use local calculation
          System.out.println("Gross pay is : "+dollars.format(_gross)); 
          System.out.println("Tax is       : "+taxrate+"%"); 
          System.out.println("Net pay is   : "+dollars.format(_net)); 
    }
```

In addition you can remove the entire `Payroll` class, and move the `calc_payroll()` method into the `ClPayroll` class. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: I change it to calc_payroll () but it shows the same value of gross pay

Comment: @YoungChoi, You _may_ need to use an override then on the `CalPayroll` version of the `calc_payroll`. I'm not quite on syntax, but this is the issue in your code. If you add `System.out.println()` with different text to the `calc_payroll()` of `Pay` and `CalPayroll` you'll see which one is called...

Comment: @YoungChoi,  In addition the `cp` is of class `CalPayroll`, and not `PayRoll` so you'll never get it to call the `PayRoll.calc_payroll()`...  This can be fixed either be moving the `PayRoll.calc_payroll()` into the `CalPayroll` class, or make `CalPayroll` extend `PayRoll`. Either way you need reread code related to extending and overriding methods, as your code is not very clean.

Comment: @YoungChoi, See the newly added note on my answer, regarding moving the `calc_payroll()` method, and removing the `Payroll()` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is how you override the `calc_payroll()` in `Payroll` that extends `Pay`, and how you call it. You are trying to return 2 different values from the `calc_payroll()` method, `_gross` in `Pay` and `net` in `Payroll`. You would be better to perform the calculation in the method, but not return a value and provide access to `_gross` and `net` via the getter methods.

So, make the following changes:

```
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import java.text.NumberFormat; 
    import java.math.*; 
    import java.util.Locale; 

    class CalPayroll extends Payroll
    { 
        Screen sc=new Screen(); 

        NumberFormat dollars=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); 

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static void main(String... args) { 
              CalPayroll cpr=new CalPayroll(); 
              cpr.acceptPay(); 

        } 

        public int acceptInputInt()   { 
               return in.nextInt(); 
           } 

        public char acceptInputChar() { 
              return in.next().charAt(0); 
       } 
        public float AcceptInputFloat()  { 
              return in.nextFloat();   
         } 
       public double AcceptInputDouble() { 
              return in.nextDouble(); 
       } 

        public void displayinfo() 
        { 

              calc_payroll(); 
              double _gross = getGross();
              tax(_gross); 
              double _net = getNet();

              System.out.println("Gross pay is : "+dollars.format(_gross)); 
              System.out.println("Tax is       : "+taxrate+"%"); 
              System.out.println("Net pay is   : "+dollars.format(_net)); 

        } 

        public void acceptPay() 
        { 
              CalPayroll cp=new CalPayroll(); 
              Screen sc = new Screen();
              float h,r; 
              int hs; 
              char s = 'a'
              while(s!='e' && s!='E') 
              {     
                    System.out.println("Payroll Computation"); 
                    System.out.println(" "); 
                    System.out.println("Enter number of hours worked (00.0) <0 for Quick exit>: "); 
                    h=stdin.nextFloat(); 
                    cp.setHours(h); 
                    if(h>0) 
                    { 
                          System.out.println("Enter first number of hours straight (integer or 0 to disable):"); 
                          hs=stdin.nextInt(); 
                          System.out.println("Enter hourly rate of worker (00.00): "); 
                          r=stdin.nextFloat(); 
                          sc.scrollscreen('=' as char,65,2); 
                          cp.setHrsStr(hs); 
                          cp.setRate(r); 

                          sc.scrollscreen(1); 
                          cp.displayinfo(); 
                          sc.scrollscreen(1); 

                          System.out.println("e to exit, any other letter + <Enter> to continue"); 
                          s=stdin.next().charAt(0); 

                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                          System.out.println("e to exit, any other letter + <Enter> to continue"); 
                          s=stdin.next().charAt(0); 
                    } 

              }

        } 
    } 

    class Pay 
    { 
        private float Hours, Rate; 
        private int HrsStr; 
        public int taxrate=0; 
        double gross;


        public void setHours(float a) 
        { 
              Hours=a; 
        } 
        public void setRate(float a) 
        { 
              Rate=a; 
        } 
        public void setHrsStr(int a) 
        { 
              if(a<0) 
              { 
                    HrsStr=0; 
              } 
              else 
              { 
                    HrsStr=a; 
              } 
        } 
        public float getHours() 
        { 
              return Hours; 
        } 
        public float getRate() 
        { 
              return Rate; 
        } 
        public int getHrsStr() 
        { 
              return HrsStr; 
        } 

        public double getGross(){
            return gross;
        }


        public void calc_payroll() 
        { 
              gross=getHours()*getRate(); 
        } 

        public void tax(double a) 
        { 
              if(a>=0&&a<=399.99) 
                 taxrate=7; 
              else if(a>=400.00&&a<=899.99) 
                 taxrate=11; 
              else 
                 taxrate=17; 
        } 

    } 

    class Payroll extends Pay 
    { 
        double net; 

        public void calc_payroll() 
        { 
              super.calc_payroll(); 
              super.tax(getGross()); 
              net = getGross() - (getGross() * taxrate / 100); 
        } 


        public double getNet(){
            return net;
        }
    } 

    class Screen 
    { 
        public static void scrollscreen(int a) 
         { 
               for(int i=0;i<a;i++) 
               { 
                    System.out.println(" "); 
               }   
         } 

         public static void scrollscreen(char c, int a, int b) 
         { 
               for(int i=0;i<b;i++) 
               { 
                    for(int j=0;j<a;j++) 
                    { 
                          System.out.print(c); 
                    } 
                    System.out.println(" "); 
               } 
       } 
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it just keeps showing 0.00 for the value of net pay :(

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong because I have run it and seen the correct output. I have updated the output to the complete modified code, that ran successfully for me.

Comment: Yea it works!!  I didnt code for getgross Thank you pc Zeus :)